# How to repeat select query when date within range?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with a column "Date". The date will be displayed in a calendar in a cyclic form. For example the records date will be shown in the calendar in a certain day each week till a specific date (let's say TerminationDate). To summarize in my table I have the Date and the TerminationDate columns like this:

```
Table:
Title | Date | TerminationDate
------------------------------
t1    | d1   | td1
```

and I want to achieve something like this:

```
From query:
Title | Date | TerminationDate
------------------------------
t1    | d1+7 | td1
t1    | d1+14| td1
t1    | d1+21| td1
.................... till Date < TerminationDate
```

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this in Oracle?

Comment: need it with SQL or PLSQL?

Comment: I would like with SQL because I am not very practical with PLSQL but as you wish, no problem :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
select distinct title, date +  ( level * 7 ), termination_date 
 from table 
  connect by  date +  ( level * 7 ) < termination_date
```

EDIT:

Forget about above query, since the rows must be connected only with itself there has to be

```
connect_by prior title = title
```

but that means a loop must be created. Unfortunately Oracle connect by clause throws an error if there is a loop whatsoever. Even if you use

```
date +  ( level * 7 ) < termination_date
```

Oracle still stops execution immediately where it detects a loop at runtime. Using nocycle returns the result, but that returns only the first record which is date + 7

**ANSWER**:

So i had to approach to the problem in a different way

```
select t.*, date + (r * 7) as the_date
 from table t,
   (select rownum as r
      from dual
    connect by level < (select max(weeks) --max date interval as weeks to be used to repeat each row as much, if you know the max weeks difference you can use the constant number instead of this sub-query
                          from (select ceil((termination_date - date) / 7) as weeks 
                                  from table ))
)
 where r < ceil((termination_date - date) / 7)
```

Let me know is there is any conufsion or performance problem

Comment: Thanks but in this case also, like the answer left by Gaurav, the time of processing is too high. This is because the query is processing again and again some records that have the Date smaller than the Date of the other record. So after each record processed, these records whose date is smaller than the previous are processed again and again.. Any other idea?

Comment: Yes you are right, does it take too much ? That one came into my mind first. Let me have another look

Comment: ..actually infinitely because of what I told you above. Please tell me any other idea you think should work :)

Comment: Well, it is not infinite. I executed it with a table of 10 tupples.     date +  ( level * 7 ) < termination_date condition would not let it execute infinetly. Btw, do you have unique values of title field ?

Comment: Excuse me for replying now, my table is a little bigger (more than 200 rows). I have one column as unique field for each row

Comment: Well 200-300 rows are nothing for Oracle for this query really ( depends on the data range too, but still i imagine it is not decades between the termination_date and date, or is it ? ), it shouldn't be taking much time. It is kind of odd that it takes much time. I can't really think of a better solution with SQL.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35280/discussion-between-albano-vito-and-brhneser)

Comment: I knew you would find it, thank you again and again. This works perfectly and runs smoothly. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested the query ,but it should work like as you need

```
    SELECT t1, d1 + (7 * LEVEL), termination_date
      FROM tab
     WHERE d1 + (7 * LEVEL) < termination_date
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= CEIL( (termination_date - d1) / 7);
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1,dt,termination_date
FROM( 
SELECT t1, d1 + (7 * LEVEL) dt, termination_date
  FROM tab
 WHERE d1 + (7 * LEVEL) < termination_date
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= CEIL( (termination_date - d1) / 7)
);
```

Comment: Thanks but this gives me only selects for one record, how to make it select all cases for all records of the table?

Comment: It is fine, excuse me for replying without testing, Thank you very much :)

Comment: Excuse me one more time, because I am getting some rows repetitively like forever, can you please give me a hint how to make this select for each row in my table? (all together)

Comment: Using distinct in my case has a problem ,the query is too slow because the number of rows is high. Do you have another idea? Hope I am not bothering you :)

Comment: @AlbanoVito:Please find the edit solution , you need to wrap the result over another select ,that will be faster i think

Comment: Thanks again but even in this case the query is too slow. I think that I need some kind of role not to select any more the rows that where selected before. Each row in my table has actually a unique  column number but I do not know how to process.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more way to do it

```
SELECT 
  *,
  date + ( ROWNUM * 7 ) as modified_date
FROM (
  SELECT 
    title, 
    date,
    termination_date 
  FROM 
   table 
 ) WHERE date + ( ROWNUM * 7 ) < termination_date
```

Comment: Thanks, is this faster than the above answer?

Comment: could be faster in a few ms, it would be better if you tried it against your data though

Comment: I think you got the question wrong. Each record should be repeated with date 7 days later than the previous repetition until the termination date of the given record. 

So assume there is another record with title t2 in the table given in the question, than t2 should be repeated with date increasing until t2's termination date @AlbanoVito